Inequivalent definitions of smooth lie action
In this question, it is showed that two possible definition of smoothness of lie action are inequivalent. ¿Which is the right one? In the book Geometric Mechanics and Symmetry,they define it as a group homomorphism $\Phi:G\rightarrow \operatorname{diff}(M)$, while in Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry or Lectures on Symplectic Geometry, they define as an smooth map $\Phi:G \times M \rightarrow M$. ¿Which definition is the right one?

The second definition is the right one. The first one is "not smooth enough" (asks for no smoothness in the variable $G$).
